# Grails URL Mapping - if URL doesn't match fall back to application root page

Tags: grails, spring-boot

I am working on my first Grails + Spring Boot appcation along with React JS to build a single page application.

The landing page is index.gsp

I am facing little trouble with UrlMappings.

What I want to achieve is, if url doesn't start with /api/** or /assets/** then it should be redirected to / (root - index.gsp).

As of now, it is giving me 403, forbidden error, if i refresh my single page application.

Do let me know if you need any other information.

Regards,
Priyank Thakkar

Comment: I did not try, but it may work to define another redirect from 403 to your index: "403" (controller: 'home', action: 'index')

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.

In my **URLMappings.groovy**, I had to enter

```
"/**"(view:"/index")
```

at end of the file after all the mappings are done.

Comment: I upvoted this but I was not able to get it to work. Did you need to handle any spring security filtering in a special way because I'm getting a stackoverflow and security exceptions.